# Historical Mutual funds

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the Indian mutual funds historical data in my database, is there a way to do that without individually downloading data for all the funds.

I tried downloading the data from the AMFI website but the data is so large and doing it individually for every fund would take a lot of time is there a way to get it directly in my database

Comment: are you trying this on your personal laptop or do you have a dedicated server to do this? Also, what are you trying to achieve by doing this, is your end goal to perform analytics for a client or doing it just for a hobby? 

There are multiple ways this can be implemented and the cost might vary

Comment: There's no magic "put data somehow in my database" function. You could write a program to get the data from the website and insert it to your database.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is to write an extraction script in python/bash or any other language of choice and extract data in s3.

then write a load script which is just a bunch of copy commands to load data into a choice of databases like Postgres or Snowflake.

To make things better you can write extract and load script to some sort of date filtering by the hour or day, and use something like Apache airflow to create a pipeline that performs this on a scheduled basis. Airflow also has the ability to backfill data and it will create a job for individual hour/day which will run in parallel based on parallelism setting you decide